# Почему некоторые места прозрачные, при импорте модели из Substance Painter?

Tags: unity3d, substance-painter

Мы создаем игру на Unity и возникла небольшая проблема. При импорте модели некоторые места прозрачные, что не очень хорошо смотрится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете помочь с этим?

Answer (score 0):

Substance Painter тут скорее всего не при чем - он же только текстуры "рисует".

Зачастую, по умолчанию, поверхности односторонние (то есть полигоны "смотрят" в одну сторону и с нее видны, а с другой стороны - нет). Вам надо где-то выставить галку "двухстороннести" / "Doublesided" в настройкам модели/материалов.

Вот тут вот например нету ли варианта "Front and Back"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]